# const logger = reduxLogger.createLogger(); ^ TypeError: reduxLogger.createLogger is not a function

Tags: react-redux, redux-logger

I am using logger for redux react as a middleware. But when i passed the command node index it says create logger is not a function. So I do not why it says.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
 
const logger = createLogger();
 
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(logger)
);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.